# Node: Get var from JS file from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a request call that will call a javascript file that contains a var:

```
var url = 'http://' + _environment + '/services.js';

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
       _services = body;
   }

   console.log(_services);
});
```

This will log something like the following:

```
var services = {
     "production": {
          "global": {
               "id": "id",
               "test2": "http://test.com",
               "test": "/test/test.test",
               "test1": "test"
          }
     }
}
```

So to be exact, this line is equivalent to what I am ending up with:

```
var _services = var services = {
     "production": {
          "global": {
               "id": "id",
               "test2": "http://test.com",
               "test": "/test/test.test",
               "test1": "test"
          }
     }
}
```

How to I pass a var from a js file located at some url to my code?

Comment: i would either make it a json file, or load it in a script tag and take it from the global scope.

Comment: I cannot change the file itself, but I can look into the global scope idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `exec(_services)`, but a better idea would be to just drop the `var` part and return regular JSON, then parse the JSON.

Make it return this..

```
{
     "production": {
          "global": {
               "id": "id",
               "test2": "http://test.com",
               "test": "/test/test.test",
               "test1": "test"
          }
     }
}
```

Then just do `var services = JSON.parse(_services);`

---

Alternatively, you can create a script tag and append it..

```
// This is with jQuery, you can convert to standard JS
$("body").append("<script>"+_services+"</script>");
```